# C# csv write each word in separate column

Tags: c#, csv

I want to write each word in a separate column cell in csv. My code:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename, false);
tw.WriteLine("var1, var2");
tw.Close();

tw = new StreamWriter(filename, true);

tw.WriteLine(floatType1 + "," + floatType2);

tw.Close();
```

Currently, "var1, var2" gets displayed in one cell and floatType1, floatType2 in one cell below the previous cell. How to fix this?

Comment: What are the values of `floatType1` and `floatType2`?

Comment: Depends on editor. Usual csv separator is ; instead of , When loading on excel or similar you need to choose the proper delimiter to open in different cells.